# Is it possible to create SFTP(Not FTP) user using c#? If it is then how?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp, sftp, filezilla

Creating SFTP(Not FTP) user account through c# code.
Is this possible to create sftp users by my code? I'm using bitvise SSH server as my sftp server, and filezilla server as my ftp server, now I want to create different users for my different employees so that they all would have access of different folders on my server and could not be able to access each others path (folders).Can anyone have some idea of user creation in sftp by c# code?

Comment: Maybe this is helpful https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=5228

Comment: Have you done any research? Googling for "c# sftp" produces plenty of useful pages.

Comment: @Kenster : i have done research but nothing i get..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) For make windows bitvise ssh server Account

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var cfg = new CBssCfg726("BssCfg726.BssCfg726");
            cfg.SetSite("Bitvise SSH Server");
            cfg.LockServerSettings();
            cfg.LoadServerSettings();

            cfg.settings.access.winAccountsEx.@new.winDomain = "Domain_Name";
            cfg.settings.access.winAccountsEx.@new.winAccount = "Account_Name";
            cfg.settings.access.winAccountsEx.@new.loginAllowed = cfg.DefaultYesNo.yes;
            cfg.settings.access.winAccountsEx.@new.xfer.mountPointsEx.Clear();
            cfg.settings.access.winAccountsEx.@new.xfer.mountPointsEx.@new.realRootPath = "C:\\Sftp\\User";
            cfg.settings.access.winAccountsEx.@new.xfer.mountPointsEx.NewCommit();
            cfg.settings.access.winAccountsEx.NewCommit();
            cfg.UnlockServerSettings();
            cfg.SaveServerSettings();


            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

2) For make virtual bitvise ssh server account

```
private void AssignPowerSchoolCredentials()
    {
        try
        {
            var cfg = new CBssCfg726("BssCfg726.BssCfg726");
            cfg.SetSite("Bitvise SSH Server");               
            cfg.LoadServerSettings();

            cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.@new.virtAccount = "Virtual_Account_name";
            cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.@new.virtPassword.Set("Password");
            cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.@new.group = "Virtual Users";

            //if already virtAccountsEx then first delete... 
            for (uint i = 0; i < cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.count; i++)
            {
                if (cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.GetItem(i).virtAccount == "Virtual_Account_name")
                {
                    cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.Erase(i);
                }
            }                
            cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.@new.fwding.srvSideC2S.ipv4Ex.@new.targetHost = "127.0.0.1";
            cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.@new.fwding.srvSideC2S.ipv4Ex.@new.targetPort = 80;
            cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.@new.fwding.srvSideC2S.ipv4Ex.@new.proxyProfile = "Default";
            cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.@new.loginAllowed = cfg.DefaultYesNo.yes;
            cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.@new.xfer.mountPointsEx.Clear();
            cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.@new.xfer.mountPointsEx.@new.sfsMountPath = "/";
            cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.@new.xfer.mountPointsEx.@new.realRootPath = "Folder_path";
            cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.@new.xfer.mountPointsEx.NewCommit();
            cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.@new.fwding.srvSideC2S.ipv4Ex.NewCommit();
            cfg.settings.access.virtAccountsEx.NewCommit();
            cfg.SaveServerSettings();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also add refferance for BssCfg726Lib or BssCfg721Lib or etc.,whatever in your solution.